# Multiple website on a single droplet with no Apache/Nginx

Tags: ip, webserver, hosting-services

I have a single droplet at Digital Ocean and I host my website there. It's a standalone application with a  built-in webserver. I want to host another  website on that droplet as well. It'll also be the same kind of application with a built-in webserver, but the domain will be different and the website itself also will be different. That is, 2 different websites. The port should be the same: 443. The ip address will be different probably, although I'm not sure because it's a single droplet.

I know I can do that. But on Digital Ocean they say that I'll have to do that via Apache or Nginx. Is it a requirement? If not, how can I setup all that without them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can can run two application in same port as DO is not providing additional IP's for Droplet. I would say try running the application using Nginx Proxy or Apache Proxy

Comment: ok. I have a droplet of 512 Mb for $5/month, the basic one. do you think 2 websites with nginx will work fast enough on it given that I have 200 visitors per day for them both at best?

Comment: It depends upon the memory/CPU requirements for the application and nginx will be perfect(low resource consumption).

Comment: I think it consumes relatively low memory, it's in Haskell.